# reading a text file into an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm really new to programming, and after thinking hard about this for a week for a summer project, I'd really appreciate some help!

I'm trying to read in a long text file, which is just a long string (NB: not an actual programming string) of letters, and then put each letter into its place in the grid (the aim of the program is ultimately to solve a wordsearch) so far I've come up with the program below, which doesn't seem to be producing a grid, but rather just reprints the text file, preceded by the following:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1138\cocoasubrtf510    
{\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11905\paperh16837\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720

\f0\fs24 \cf0
```

The program that I've written is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char myarray[26][26],x;
    FILE *myfile;

    for (j=0; j<26; j++)                 //initialise array elements all to zero
    {
        for (i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
            myarray[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    myfile=fopen("*redacted*","r");
    if (myfile!=NULL) //check file actually opened
    {
        for (i=0; i<26; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<26; j++)
            {
                fscanf(myfile,"%c",&x); //read the values in
                myarray[i][j]=x;
            }
        }
        // data is now in the array called myarray
        fclose(myfile);        
    }

    else
    {
        printf("File not found");
    }

    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
            printf("%c",myarray[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: +1 for indenting the code (more or less) so it's readable, and for doing error checking too. Rare bird.

Comment: However, a question: what do you mean by "it doesn't seem to be producing an array"? You **do** have the array: it's the `myarray` object (variable).

Comment: the program outputs the text file like so:
Mniparogocomputerhardwareywoieeoonodsmecivedegarotspesdfnidpctatrtnytrrrorcreoggimtnatosotmdroeoamupeuciwngbytekmgtoaeanrsnmgtdtittiimrehpponnnidtosdruamhvoaetmogeiuiutemouseopommaeyreaamrtvtfltnmslscmeedctdepulmeaioerkatluieoaredsitasyiamtrrrooeleeccrcyprkyunlontmewgsirsyricopcpoabgpetifgrddyorecsbimrdereapnnckoorecarfrhitnoiprscgstripeoratieotbpaornaoosetyeeatpumotrrmwnarrterrwmprraiopitaarceeaotkeduscdeipoesoskpttoudm
preceeded by the strange text I copied in the post. I've tried checking that letters are where they should be, and they don't appear

Comment: @H2CO3 It seems OP wanted to say "grid" instead of "array"; i changed the question (hope it's a correct guess)

Comment: @anatolyg So that's formatting. Fair enough, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the beauty of C:

You can read the file in a single operation, and save yourself the looping:

Something like

```
fread(myArray, sizeof(myArray), myfile)
```

You should probably initialize the array to all zeros before you do this, though:

```
char myArray[26][26] = { 0 };
```

Or fill it with zeroes if you don't initialize it:

```
 memset(myArray, 0, sizeof(myArray));
```

Also, you might want to print a newline ("\n") at the end of each outer loop in your printing section: otherwise the file contents will appear as one long, continuous string.

Comment: One of the few beauties of C

Comment: This, however, encourages some bad practice, which is harmful to recommend to a beginner. Firstly, don't cast to `void *`, it's superfluous and the only thing it does is decreasing readability. Two, do check the return value of `fread()` - OP does seem to know about error handling, don't mislead him, because `fread()` may not read the entire array, in which case one has to retry. Three, use `sizeof(array)` instead of a hard-coded size, it's safer.

Comment: But the last line in this answer is critical to the OP - the output that is being generated will look exactly like the input file unless you add newlines to see that it's an array.

Comment: @H2CO3   Agreed on all points, but the aim was to make clear to him how to accomplish what he was doing in another way.

Comment: @curt, thanks for the help, where exactly should I put the new line entry? I've been playing around with it in different places with no success.

Comment: @user2591837 If your file has newlines, then nowhere. If it doesn't, then you print a newline after having output each row of the array (i. e. at the end of the outer loop).

Comment: @H2CO3, do you mean something like this: for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
            printf("%c",myarray[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

?

Comment: @user2591837 No, the `printf("\n")` should be one level out. But really, don't reinvent the wheel on every single line. `printf("%s\n", array[i]);` or even better `puts(array[i]);` is good enough for printing a line, you don't even need nested loops...

Comment: @user2591837 Let me correct myself: you should be rather declaring a 26 x 27 element array, and leaving room for one terminating NUL character at the end, so it's easier to print the lines.

Comment: @Curt Excuse me, but now when are you intending to fix your code, finally? (also, there's a slight terminology problem: `memset()` doesn't initialize the array. Initialization would be `char arr[26][27] = { 0 };`, and indeed, probably **that** is what you should recommend to OP instead of `memset()`.)

Comment: @H2C03   No.   The code does not have "mistakes," but rather things you would prefer were done differently.   They were intended to clarify a couple questions by a relative novice, and it's my sense that it would be clearer to him the way it is currently written.

Comment: @Curt That's unfortunately not true... Search a bit around on Stack Overflow, and you'll see that this is not my personal opinion but that of practically any experienced, professional C programmer, way smarter than both of us... These are objective facts.

Comment: @user2591837    I added the newline to your print loop with a comment in your OP code.

Comment: Um, did you even try running that?

`size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)`

You are one argument short of a correct fread call.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to do your summer project, but here's some remarks:

1) The text file is not a text file but an RTF file, which is text with formatting. You probably made/saved it using TextEdit. If so, use the 'Make Plain Text' menu item to fix this.

2) Your program seems to be doing the following: read 26x26 (why 26?) characters from a file (including spaces, newlines etcetera), put them in a 26x26 array, and then print them one by one. I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve, but it appears to have something to do with formatting the array, in which case you will probably want to think about how to handle whitespace characters in the input, and printing them yourself when generating output.